# pushing out chunked bytes as fast as possible

Tags: php, string, byte, chunks

I'm looking for a way to output data to as many clients as possible, the fastest way possible and without delay. So I thought of dividing the pre-compressed data output into chunks so the client's browsers can recognize the data sooner. Here's what I got in code so far for dividing the output into 1500 byte chunks (and I chose 1500 because that matches the server's ethernet MTU).

```
<?php
    $chunk="<about 7kb gzipped data>";
    header("Content-length: ".strlen($chunk),true);
    flush();
    while (1){
        $sz=strlen($chunk);
        if ($sz > 1500){$sz=1500;}
        echo substr($chunk,0,$sz);
        flush();
        $chunk=substr($chunk,$sz);
        $sz=strlen($chunk);
        if ($sz < 1500){break;}
    }
    echo $chunk;
    flush();
?>
```

Is there a way I can do this without calculating the string length so many times? I'm looking for basically the equivalent of what I have except that it needs to execute much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$chunk` doesn't change *during the execution of the script* then there is no need to chop up the string. All this does is waste memory by allocating multiple blocks.

PHP will **not** free your memory allocations until the script ends, and every string operation (such as `substr`) will allocate a new buffer for its result. This means that your memory usage would be an order of magnitude higher than 7kb to write this very short amount of data out.

It would be much faster (fewer `malloc` calls, which are expensive) and easier on memory (only a bit more than 7kb of memory is needed) to just write each block by pulling them directly from the master string:

```
$chunk="<about 7kb gzipped data>";
$sz=strlen($chunk);
header("Content-length: ".$sz,true);
flush();
$pos=0;    
while ($pos <= $sz){
    echo substr($chunk,$pos,1500);
    flush();
    $pos += 1500;
}
```

But, do actually test this because I bet the following is a **lot** faster because the PHP interpreter is very efficient at this sort of thing and your web server will do fairly smart buffering anyway. Trying to work around it is often a losing game.

```
$chunk="<about 7kb gzipped data>";
echo $chunk;
```

Also note that PHP [stores the length of a string in a hidden field](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details), so `strlen` is not actually an expensive operation. It is the additional memory allocations and chunked output that make this slow.

Comment: the value of `$chunk` is different at least 99% of the time.

Comment: But surely it is not different during the execution of the loop.

Comment: The value is the same in the loop and I don't think I can find an answer better than yours.